# Bluetooth Link Key on the iPhone 

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

Is there any way to get/know the stored Bluetooth link key from my iPhone device?

Is it logged anywhere?

Is it possible to dump the iPhone internal logs?

Comment: Why do you need the link key?

Comment: to be able to decrypt an air trace that i captured betweewn by iPhone and another device

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I tried doing an air trace with an iPhone a few years back but hit a dead end due to encryption. I'd be interested to hear if you found another way to debug your connection.

Comment: I need your Help Mr Dennis Mathews, please reply

Comment: can you contact me via mail, veer.developer@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can follow https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=bluetooth to get bluetooth log then get link key.